# Node.js / JavaScript can't reach object scope (?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I made this 'class' in Node:

```
function Database(in_fs, in_file){
    this.fs;
    this.file;
    this.data;

    this.fs = in_fs;
    this.file = in_file;
    fs.readFile(this.file, function(error, data){
        if(error){
            throw error;
        }
        this.data = JSON.parse(data);
    });

    this.toString = function(){
        return JSON.stringify(this.data);
    }
}
```

It gets data from a file and saves it in a variable. 
If I log the data within the readfile callback it works and shows it perfectly. However, if I run the `toString` of `Database` is shows `undefined`. I'm pretty sure this is a scope issue, but I can't seem to fix it.